# what is the difference between Adi Shakti and Adi Parashakti?

Tags: shiva, devi, shaivism, shakti, shaktism

Are Adi Shakti and Adi Para-Shakti synonyms or there's some difference between them as per Shaiva sects and Shakta sects?

if so, what is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

> Śiva says to Śakti: There is always non-difference between Śakti and
> the possessor of Śakti(Śaktimān) therefore being endowed with His
> (i.e. Śaktimān’s) attributes Śakti becomes the bearer of the same
> attributes. Therefore being non-different form para the highest e.e.
> Bhairava) She is known as Parā (the highest i.e. Bhairavi). The
> burning power of fire is not accepted as separate from the fire even
> after full consideration (even so the Parāśakti is not separate from
> Bhairava). Only it is described in a distinct way as a preliminary
> step for the listener towards its knowledge (lit., towards entry into
> its knowledge) 18-19
>
> Śiva says to Śakti: When in one who enters the state of Śakti (i.e.
> who is identified with Śakti), there ensues the feeling of
> non-distinction (between Śakti and Śiva), then he acquires the state
> of Śiva, (for) in the agamas (iha), She (Śakti) is declared as the
> door of the entrance (into Śiva, Śaivi Mukha = She is the face of
> Śiva) (Lit., Śakti is Śiva‘s face). Just as by means of the light of a
> lamp, and the rays of the Sun, portions of space, ect. are known even
> so, Oh dear on, by means of Śakti is Śiva (who is one’s essential
> Self) cognized (i.e. recognized).
> Vijñānabhairava Tantra 20-21

Article Source: [Link](http://namahshivaya.net/ishwara-shakti/)

So we Understood the concept of "Para" and "Shakti", whereas 'Adi' is to denote the first origin.